# Loading models in a class's constructor in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use the **DRY principle** here and as such am trying to assign my models to variables in my constructors.

The following class is in my library directory.

So far I have this...

```
class Cpd_handler
{
    protected $dateHelper;
    protected $userHelper;
    protected $reportsModel;
    protected $dataModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $this->dateHelper   = $CI->load->library('helpers/date_helper');
        $this->userHelper   = $CI->load->library('helpers/user_helper');
        $this->reportsModel = $CI->load->model('cpd/Reports_model');
        $this->dataModel    = $CI->load->model('Tp_data_model');    }


    public function sectorOverview($data)
    {       
        var_dump($this->dataModel);
    }
```

When I try to dump out `$this->dataModel` it just returns **NULL**.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per CI docs

```
Loader, as the name suggests, is used to load elements. 
These elements can be libraries (classes) View files, Helpers, Models, or 
your own files
```

So instead of assigning like this

```
$this->dataModel    = $CI->load->model('Tp_data_model');
```

Try

```
$CI->load->model('Tp_data_model');
$this->dataModel = $CI->Tp_data_model;
var_dump($this->dataModel);
```

Suppose you have method named get_data() in your Tp_data_model class, 
then you could use `$this->dataModel->get_data()` instead if `$CI->Tp_data_model->get_data()`